# Is Excel VBA the same as VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vba

Is VB.NET the same language that is used in Excel 2003/2007 in the user editable code you can write in the backgrouund?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Excel 2003 and 2007 use [Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), which is a variation of Visual Basic 6. This is an enormous change from [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#Relation_to_older_versions_of_Visual_Basic_.28VB6_and_previous.29) for more details about specific differences.

Answer (score 12):

No, the only similarity between VBA and VB.NET is the similar-looking syntax.

VBA is similar to Visual Basic 6, which is obsolete since about 1997 (?), so VBA is not a very modern language.

VB.NET is a modern language, having the same capabilities as C#, but the syntax is terrible, so I personally prefer C#.

VBA is an interpreted language, while VB.NET is compiled.

If you are interested in Office programming, you might consider doing your next Office project in VB.NET and VSTO, which is the modern alternative to VBA.