# .NET multiplying with Boolean value

Tags: .net, boolean, multiplication

I read that it is not recommended to rely on multiplying Boolean (True) value or use it in calculations. Also just noticed that in VB.NET True is -1 rather than 1 or any other value.

I have many situations where I'd like to multiply with Boolean True value and treating it as Integer of 1 (or -1 would also make it). **What is the suggested way to use Boolean True value in calculations**.

Comment: You haven't said what you think false * false * false / true is? So how can anyone answer? Boolean values aren't numbers.

Comment: just convert true and false to desired value and then multiplying

Answer (score 4):

If you need to make a calculation based on a value of `Boolean`, use ternary operator in C#, or the `IF` expression in VB.NET:

```
Res = SomeValue * If(MyBoolean, 1, 0) + SomeOtherValue
```

Expressions like that make your intentions clear to the reader, which improves readability even in languages that assign Booleans specific numeric values (e.g. C or C++).

Comment: I know [VB.NET differs significantly from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502788/is-excel-vba-the-same-as-vb-net), but if you want to implement in VBA, you need to use the `IIf` function as follows: `IIf(MyBoolean,1,0)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `bool` as the value `0` or `1`, corresponding to `false` and `true` respectively, then do this:

```
bool b = true;
double x = 3.14;
double y = (b ? 1 : 0) * x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) so that you don't have to guess if true is 1 or -1.

```
int product = someValue * (myBool ? 1 : 0)
```

This would also allow you to define other values to true and false.

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on this extensively I would suggest to put an extension method on bool that returns a numeric value of your choosing - based on true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you want to use a Boolean value for calculation. They are not meant for arithmetic operations.

Dont know if thats the best way but you can do this:-

```
bool b = true;
var x = 0;

if(b == true)
{
  x = -1;  // Use the value of this x anywhere you want provided the scope is clear.
}
```

Comment: The reason for using bools in calculations is to avoid branching as an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

**Initial suggestion**:
You can use the `Convert.ToInt32(bool)` method to cast the bool to an int.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Boolean_

**New suggestion**:
You can use pointers in C# inside code blocks with the **unsafe** keyword (NOTE that you also have to enable that in your build options).
For more info see: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pointers-and-unsafe-code/

A code snippet from: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pointers-in-C-Sharp/

```cs
unsafe
{
    char c = 'R';  
    char *pc = &c;  
    void *pv = pc; // Implicit conversion  
    int *pi = (int *) pv; // Explicit conversion using casting operator
}
```

If you make an int pointer to keep the address of the bool, you should be able to make the program read the memory address of the bool as if it was an int. So something along the lines of:

```cs
    unsafe class Program
    {
        unsafe static int AddBools(bool* a, bool* b)
        {
            /*casts the bool pointer to a byte pointer and then uses the *
            operator to access the value at the position as a byte, which you can
            use in calculations (both data types are 8-bit)*/ 
            return (*(byte*)a) + (*(byte*)b);
        }

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool a = false;
            bool b = true;

            Console.WriteLine("a+a = " + AddBools(&a, &a)); //prints 0
            Console.WriteLine("a+b = " + AddBools(&a, &b)); //prints 1
            Console.WriteLine("b+b = " + AddBools(&b, &b)); //prints 2

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Just keep in mind the difference in bit numbering between signed/unsigned and integer/floating types.
Here are links to the wiki page for bit numbering and a list of the different data types and their sizes in C#:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-data-types

Comment: I think this is an useful method, but I don't think that's what the question is looking for.

Comment: @Gianmarco but that's one way to convert the bool into an integer value that can be used in mathemathical operations such as `4*Convert.ToInt32(true);`, which would equal 4 or `return 4*Convert.ToInt32(a) + 6*Convert.ToInt32(!a);` which would be a branchless way of returning 4 or 6. Isn't that the essence of the question?

Comment: I completely agree that this answers the question asked, but be aware that it isn't purely branchless.  See [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.cs#L1059), which uses the ternary operator (and so presumably turns into a conditional branch).

Comment: @Jarak I modified the answer with a different example, casting pointers instead. I don't completely trust what I've done though since it's the first time working with it. Would be nice to get some verification :)

Comment: It does indeed seem to do what you intend :)  See [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Jarak-Jakar/842c708f726c2bb531e27517866a30ee) (modified slightly to let it run without issue in LINQPad/RoslynPad - doesn't affect the core logic of your sample).

Comment: @Jarak Thanks, I appreciate you taking your time and double checking it :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exact circumstances, you *might* want to use the [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-5.0) or [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-5.0) interfaces.  E.g. if you already have some sort of ordering comparison which produces a bool that you then convert and multiply against, it would probably be better just to use one of those interfaces and multiply against the result directly than perform the comparison, get a bool, convert the bool and *then* multiply.

Watch out, though, since they both can return a negative number depending on the ordering of the arguments.  Also, this will probably only be of any use when the bool produced was the product of an ordering comparison to begin with.