# Do I need to create a new object just to change the font style on a DataGridView userform?

Tags: vb.net

I've been using VBA for over 2 years but recently started learning VB.NET.  There are more differences than I expected, including this line required just to make the font bold in the first line of my DataGridView:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
```

In VBA to make something bold it would have just been something like

```
Range("A1").fontstyle.bold = True
```

My question is what is actually happening in that line of VB code.  Is it constructing a new object just to use a property from the "Font" class which is an enumeration for bold?  I've just never seen something like this.

Comment: You could make it bold via the IDE designer

Comment: I'm not adding the row until the form loads...but I'm more curious about understanding what's taking place in this line of code/why you need to construct a new object

Comment: You can't change the font style. To do so, you should create a new font using the given font and set its new style.

Comment: vba is much less OO (if at all, being based on 1998 tech);   even if you do it via the IDE it has to be done...it is just that VS does it for you in the form's designer code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net is an Object Orientated Programming language, while its syntax is similar to VBA which may assist you in learning it, it is a very different language. [Is Excel VBA the same as VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502788/is-excel-vba-the-same-as-vb-net)

Font is an Object (a Class) within the System.Drawing Namespace
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The line you provided does the following;

1. Instantiates a new Object (a Class) of type Font. It does this via one of the Class Contructor methods. The Constructor Method used sets the FontStyle to Bold. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and more specifically https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
2. Sets the DataGridView DefaultCellStyle.Font property equal to the new Font.

The important points here are the Font Property on the DataGridView is expecting an Object (a Class) of type Font. Your code sets that Property equal to the new object.

To answer your question *"Do I need to create a new object just to change the font style on a DataGridView userform?"* the answer is yes.

The Bold property on the Font class is read only. It has a Get but no Set. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This means, unfortunately you cannot simply do this;

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).DefaultCellStyle.Font.Bold = True
```

You will have to set the Property to a new Font.