# Creating a code of drawing in NX, but results are shown

Tags: drawing

Hello I am using the Journaling function of NX 12 with visual basic, now I am trying to construct two lines, however, after I run my program, no results are shown. May I ask what is wrong with my code?
The following is my code

Thank you

```
Imports System
Imports NXOpen
Module NXJournal
Sub Main()
Dim p0 As New NXOpen.Point3d(1,2,3)
Dim p1 As New NXOpen.Point3d(4,7,5)
Dim theSession = NXOpen.Session.GetSession()
Dim workPart As NXOpen.Part = theSession.Parts.Work
Dim line1 As NXOpen.Line = workPart.Curves.CreateLine(p0, p1)
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This is not vbscript. Possibly VBA or VB.Net

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the programming world, really have no idea about the difference between these. Could you please kindly explain a bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384051/what-is-the-difference-between-vb-and-vbscript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502788/is-excel-vba-the-same-as-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

After i run your journal, i do get a line drawn, so nothing appears to be wrong with your code.

While it should also work in other environments, i'm just going to make sure it's in the modelling inveronment for the least trouble.

Now, i've added code to fit the window to view the line to better see the line.

Another possible issue i could think of, was that you disabled the layer on which the line was drawn. To ensure this is not the case, i set the line to layer 1. To access the layer manager in nx, you can press ctrl+L, and verify what layers are visible.

```
Imports System
Imports NXOpen
Module NXJournal
Sub Main()
Dim theSession = NXOpen.Session.GetSession()
Dim workPart As NXOpen.Part = theSession.Parts.Work

' if nx is not in the modeling application, switch to it
If theSession.ApplicationName IsNot "UG_APP_MODELING" Then theSession.ApplicationSwitchImmediate("UG_APP_MODELING")

' create simple points (not smartpoints)
Dim p0 As New NXOpen.Point3d(1,2,3)
Dim p1 As New NXOpen.Point3d(4,7,5)

' create a line in the part
Dim line1 As NXOpen.Line = workPart.Curves.CreateLine(p0, p1)

'set the layer
line1.layer = 1

' fit to the line
workPart.ModelingViews().WorkView().Fit()

End Sub
End Module
```